# Can I create an asp.net website and host it with wordpress?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, upload, edit, host

First of all, I know very little about Wordpress. I'm still learning, and if I find a solution myself, I will share it here.

I've got a task to redesign a webpage. But it is currently hosted and designed with Wordpress. So I was thinking if there's a way for me to create a whole new website in visual studio and just upload those files and only use wordpress as a hosting site, and not use their design templates?

It sounds simple to me but so far I have little knowledge about the Wordpress interface. I can't find where to place those files, if it's even possible to do so.

Possible or not? Is it just me who overlooks the obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean a Wordpress.com hosted site, no - Wordpress.com is for Wordpress, not .NET.

If you mean a site running Wordpress as a content engine, the answer's still mostly no. Wordpress is designed for a LAMP stack, and while the LAM part of that can be substituted with varying amounts of work, the PHP is what Wordpress is written in.

The only direct conversion that I can think of, such as it is, would be to find or design a wordpress-like .NET CMS and hook it up to WP's database. Then you can use the content the site already possesses, at least. But by and large, no, you're trying to mix two completely different technologies.